# collision event and display.newGroup. How to connect them together? Corona

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I have a problem. According to the code below, I create an object x times (in this case 20 times) and add into a ballGroup. Moreover every one object should has body and react on "collision" physics event. But all of created balls haven't assigned body property (after putting them into ballGroup). So I think there is a problem (when I insert ball into ballGroup). When I try to addBody to whole ballGroup (line with comment), only last ball has Body property. Any idea how to solve this problem?

```
ballGroup = display.newGroup();
ballGroup.collision = onCollision;
ballGroup:addEventListener("collision", ballGroup);
-- physics.addBody(ballGroup,"dynamic", {density = 1, friction = 0, bounce = 1, radius = 10});

for i = 1,20 do
    spawnBall();
end

function spawnBall()
    ball = display.newImage("image.png");
    ball.x = math.random(-W/2, W/2);
    ball.y = math.random(-H/2, H/2);
    physics.addBody(ball,"dynamic", {density = 1, friction = 0, bounce = 1, radius = 10});
    ballGroup:insert(ball);
end

function onCollision(event)
    print("123");
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your ball local everytime you call spawnball()

```
 ballGroup = display.newGroup();
    ballGroup.collision = onCollision;
    ballGroup:addEventListener("collision", ballGroup);
    -- physics.addBody(ballGroup,"dynamic", {density = 1, friction = 0, bounce = 1, radius = 10});

    for i = 1,20 do
        spawnBall();
    end

    function spawnBall()
        local ball = display.newImage("image.png");
        ball.x = math.random(-W/2, W/2);
        ball.y = math.random(-H/2, H/2);
        physics.addBody(ball,"dynamic", {density = 1, friction = 0, bounce = 1, radius = 10});
        ballGroup:insert(ball);
        ball.collision = onCollision
        ball:addEventListener( "collision", ball )

    end

    function onCollision(event)
        print("123");
    end
```

Comment: Hi DevfaR. It actually doesn't solve problem. Now only last ball has body property and react on physical contact.

Comment: did you try putting collision inside swapBall() method because every ball need to have collisionEvent